# Which is correct: "There are not any employees" or "There is not any employee"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, there-is

Sometimes I see two variants of following sentence:

- "there are not any employees" in the department
- "there is not any employee" in the department

What is the correct sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you are referring to more than one subject, I would go with:

> There are not any employees in the department.

For referring to a single instance, I would go with "there is no"

> There is no employee in the department.

If the topic has no plural form (or is rarely used with a plural form), then I would consider "there isn't any":

> "There isn't any water" = There is no water

Comment: water is uncountable.

Comment: @Shinto: a/ I never said otherwise in my answer: as a substance, water is a mass noun. b/ you can find water with an 's': "territorial waters". Other examples: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=195932

Comment: And as a variation, "There are no employees" feels more natural to me than "not any"; but the point is we generally agree on the plural, because most departments would have more than one employee.

Comment: On its own, the second example doesn't sound right, unless you specify which employee you're talking about, e.g. "there is no employee in this department called John".

Answer (score 7):

I'd use

> There are no employees.

Answer (score 4):

"There are not any employees" is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I think that  *not any* is usually replaced by  *no* or, in case you want to stress it, *not a single*, when applied to countable nouns.

When you shorten *not* to *'nt*, you can use *any* with either the singular or the plural, but I think the plural is more common. With the singular I would use *a single* again instead of *any*. There seems to be a plural connotation to *any*.

I think these sentences are grammatically correct, but they sound *off*, the first one more than the second:

> There is not any employee here.
>   There isn't any employee here.

Much more idiomatic would be either using *a single*, using *no*, or using the plural:

> There is not a single employee here.
>   There isn't a single employee here.
>  
>   There is no employee here.
>   There are not any employees here.
>   There aren't any employees here.

Of course, with mass nouns, you *do* use the singular together with *any*, although *no* can also be used:

> There isn't any time to finish he work!
>   There is no time to finish the work!

Answer (score 0):

"are" would be the correct verb form to match the plural noun "employees".

The most idiomatic form in Canada is "There aren't any employees in the department." A more formal construction, depending on the context, would be "The department has no employees."